# Receiving whole string in uart sending data

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, uart, nodemcu

I connect my NodeMCU to Arduino Uno. The goal is to receive the whole string for example "12", every 1 sec.

This is my code on Arduino Uno side ( the sender)

```
int mock = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  s.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    //Write mock to NodeMCU
    s.print((int)mock,DEC);
    s.println();

    mock++;
    delay(1000);
}
```

On NodeMCU side ( the receiver)

```
 char data; //Initialized variable to store recieved data
 String line;
 void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
   s.begin(115200);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; 
  }
}

void loop() {

    if( s.available() >= 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i< 2; i++ ) {
            data = s.read();
            line += data;
        }
        delay(1000);
    }


    Serial.print(line);

}
```

But the result on the serial panel is not what I expected
[![Serial terminal][1]][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGC3k.png

How can I make it so that I can receive something like

```
12
(wait one sec)
13
(wait one sec)
....
```

Node MCU just prints the whole thing, I can't delay it.

Comment: crosspost https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/69844/receive-whole-string-in-serial-sending-data

Comment: Sorry, but is it violate anything though.